# Почему не работает в хроме?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть сайт: http://demo.infinity-web.site/max4/
Проблема в шапке, в хромиум-басед браузерах не подгружается деккорация.

Ниже скриншот из фаерфокса, так и должно быть.
[image: Результат как он должен быть, в фаерфоксе -- работает.]

Ниже скриншот из вивальди, так быть не должно.
[image: Сама проблема]

Код CSS/HTML:

```css
header .main-container {
  position: relative;
}

.main-screen-phone {
  font-size: 33px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
}

header {
  position: relative;
}

.main-nav {
  padding-top: 92px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.main-screen-section,
.main-nav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 15;
}

header .logo {
  width: 444px;
  height: 111px;
}

header .logo-title {
  font-size: 23px;
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  line-height: 1.2;
}

header .phone {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 44px;
  padding-right: 90px;
}

header .phone:hover {
  transform: scale(1.3);
}

header .phone::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -15px;
  right: 0;
  width: 64px;
  height: 64px;
  background-image: url('../img/main-screen-phone-decor.svg');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
}

header::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 692px;
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient( -44deg, rgb(255, 110, 2) 0%, rgb(255, 238, 51) 0%, rgb(255, 224, 26) 47%, rgb(255, 210, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient( -44deg, rgb(255, 110, 2) 0%, rgb(255, 238, 51) 0%, rgb(255, 224, 26) 47%, rgb(255, 210, 0) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient( -44deg, rgb(255, 110, 2) 0%, rgb(255, 238, 51) 0%, rgb(255, 224, 26) 47%, rgb(255, 210, 0) 100%);
  z-index: -1;
}

header .main-container::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 1406px;
  height: 692px;
  background-image: url('../img/main-screen-decor-white.svg'), url('../img/main-screen-phone-decor-two.svg');
  background-size: contain, 680px 522px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat, no-repeat;
  background-position: 0 408px, 602px -90px;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="main-container">
    <nav class="main-nav">
      <div>
        <img class="logo" src="img/logo.svg" alt="логотип: мощные пылесосы для маникюра и педикюра">
      </div>
      <p class="phone"><a href="tel://+7 800 555 17 69">+7 (800) 555 17 69</a></p>
    </nav>
    <section class="main-screen-section">
      <div class="main-text-container">
        <h1 class="main-screen-utp">Настольный пылесос для маникюра Max <span lang="en">Ultimate</span> 4 со сверхмощностью 65 Вт от производителя
        </h1>
        <b class="main-screen-lead">Забудьте, что такое маникюрная пыль навсегда и позаботьтесь наконец о своём здоровье</b>
        <div class="main-screen-btn-container">
          <a class="btn" onclick="showPayForm()">Заказать пылесос</a>
          <a class="btn" href="#about">Узнать подробнее</a>
        </div>
        <h2 class="main-screen-part-two-title"><span lang="en">Max Ultimate 4</span> станет вашим надежным помощником</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="main-screen-poster">
        <img class="" width="810" heigh="810" src="img/poster-mainscreen.png">
        <a onclick="showYu()"><img class="main-screen-poster-play" src="img/main-screen-poster-decor.svg"></a>
      </div>
      <ul class="main-screen-list">
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <p>Пыль вредна</p>
            <p class="title">Отлично впитывает маникюрную пыль</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <p>Избавьтесь от маски</p>
            <p class="title">Удобный регулятор оборотов</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <p>Гарантия</p>
            <p class="title">Гарантия 24 месяца</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <p>Тихая работа</p>
            <p class="title">Избавьтесь от маски для лица</p>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li>
          <div class="container">
            <p>Мощнее обычного</p>
            <p class="title">В 4 раза мощнее обычного маникюрного пылесоса</p>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </section>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Похоже, у Вас svg кривые. Попробовал пересохранить их в иллюстраторе, и она вообще вываливается в ошибку. ) Любая другая картинка в Вашем же коде - срабатывает. Так что, ищите проблему в этом.

Comment: Спасибо. Изображения проверить не подумал, слепо доверился дизайнеру.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
проще всего svg конвертировать в png
background-image: url('../img/main-screen-decor-white.png'), url('../img/main-screen-phone-decor-two.png');
либо открываем svg в редакторе и меняем
xlink:href="data:img/svg;
на
xlink:href="data:image/svg;
```